# ASP.NET core 2 act as reverse proxy usering rewrite middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm struggling to make my asp.net core 2 app act like a reverse proxy using URL Rewrite rules.

I have the following in my startup.cs:

```
var rewriteRules = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRedirectToHttps();
                .AddRewrite(@"^POC/(.*)", "http://192.168.7.73:3001/$1", true);
app.UseRewriter(rewriteRules);
```

The rewrite rule is exactly as it is in my IIS settings (which I'm trying to replace with this method) which works fine.

I'm assuming it has something to do with forwarding the headers maybe? Or maybe I just don't understand how the Rewrite Middleware is supposed to work, if you want the requests to be forwarded instead of just rewritten relative to current hostname.

Comment: Exactly what does not work?

Comment: Sorry, well, the app seems to use the rewrite rule to simply route to the root of my reverse proxy app. So, in the example, lets say my reverse proxy app runs on localhost, then http://localhost/poc routes to http://localhost. If I add to the url, say /poc/mycontroller/action I get 404 (even if said route is valid on my reverse proxy app)

Comment: The rewrite middleware will only change the current HttpContext.Request.Path. It will not redirect or call to any external service. There are a poc rep in aspnet github [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy)

Comment: @Dynde I assume you did not find the answer here, right? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting If so, could you please clarify the purpose of what you are trying to do to help us netter understand your need, and maybe propose an alternative solution for that?

Comment: Well, as @Kalten says, the rewrite middleware doesn't seem to fit my use case. I have not found a way to get the Proxy Kalten refers to, to work either. 
I think for my situation, I'll have to rely on IIS for my reverse proxy needs. My main issue with this, is that I'm trying to create dynamic reverse proxy mappings, and as such I'd need to modify the web.config file of the IIS Application. I will most likely just have to do this, and rely on application recycles (from the application) to enable the new reverse proxy mappings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A reverse proxy can be emulated/implemeted within a middleware :

First the startup class where we add a IUrlRewriter service and the ProxyMiddleware.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IUrlRewriter>(new SingleRegexRewriter(@"^/POC/(.*)", "http://192.168.7.73:3001/$1"));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps());
        app.UseMiddleware<ProxyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Next we will create a basic implementation of IUrlRewriter. The RewriteUri method must transform the HttpContext into an absolute Uri. Or null if the url should not be redirected in the middleware.

```
public interface IUrlRewriter
{
    Task<Uri> RewriteUri(HttpContext context);
}

public class SingleRegexRewriter : IUrlRewriter
{
    private readonly string _pattern;
    private readonly string _replacement;
    private readonly RegexOptions _options;

    public SingleRegexRewriter(string pattern, string replacement)
        : this(pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.None) { }

    public SingleRegexRewriter(string pattern, string replacement, RegexOptions options)
    {
        _pattern = pattern ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
        _replacement = replacement ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
        _options = options;
    }

    public Task<Uri> RewriteUri(HttpContext context)
    {
        string url = context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString;
        var newUri = Regex.Replace(url, _pattern, _replacement);

        if (Uri.TryCreate(newUri, UriKind.Absolute, out var targetUri))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(targetUri);
        }

        return Task.FromResult((Uri)null);
    }
}
```

And then the Middleware (stolen from an old verison of aspnet proxy [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/)) and customized. It get the IUrlRewrite service as parameter of `Invoke` method.

The pipeline is :

- Try rewrite url
- Create a HttpRequestMessage
- Copy Request Header and content
- Send the request
- Copy response header
- Copy response content
- done

Et voila

```
public class ProxyMiddleware
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        MaxConnectionsPerServer = int.MaxValue,
        UseCookies = false,
    });

    private const string CDN_HEADER_NAME = "Cache-Control";
    private static readonly string[] NotForwardedHttpHeaders = new[] { "Connection", "Host" };

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ProxyMiddleware> _logger;

    public ProxyMiddleware(
           RequestDelegate next,
           ILogger<ProxyMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IUrlRewriter urlRewriter)
    {
        var targetUri = await urlRewriter.RewriteUri(context);

        if (targetUri != null)
        {
            var requestMessage = GenerateProxifiedRequest(context, targetUri);
            await SendAsync(context, requestMessage);

            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }

    private async Task SendAsync(HttpContext context, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
        using (var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.RequestAborted))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode;

            foreach (var header in responseMessage.Headers)
            {
                context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
            }

            foreach (var header in responseMessage.Content.Headers)
            {
                context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
            }

            context.Response.Headers.Remove("transfer-encoding");

            if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(CDN_HEADER_NAME))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add(CDN_HEADER_NAME, "no-cache, no-store");
            }

            await responseMessage.Content.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
        }
    }

    private static HttpRequestMessage GenerateProxifiedRequest(HttpContext context, Uri targetUri)
    {
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
        CopyRequestContentAndHeaders(context, requestMessage);

        requestMessage.RequestUri = targetUri;
        requestMessage.Headers.Host = targetUri.Host;
        requestMessage.Method = GetMethod(context.Request.Method);


        return requestMessage;
    }

    private static void CopyRequestContentAndHeaders(HttpContext context, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
    {
        var requestMethod = context.Request.Method;
        if (!HttpMethods.IsGet(requestMethod) &&
            !HttpMethods.IsHead(requestMethod) &&
            !HttpMethods.IsDelete(requestMethod) &&
            !HttpMethods.IsTrace(requestMethod))
        {
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(context.Request.Body);
            requestMessage.Content = streamContent;
        }

        foreach (var header in context.Request.Headers)
        {
            if (!NotForwardedHttpHeaders.Contains(header.Key))
            {
                if (header.Key != "User-Agent")
                {
                    if (!requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray()) && requestMessage.Content != null)
                    {
                        requestMessage.Content?.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value.ToArray());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string userAgent = header.Value.Count > 0 ? (header.Value[0] + " " + context.TraceIdentifier) : string.Empty;

                    if (!requestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, userAgent) && requestMessage.Content != null)
                    {
                        requestMessage.Content?.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, userAgent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private static HttpMethod GetMethod(string method)
    {
        if (HttpMethods.IsDelete(method)) return HttpMethod.Delete;
        if (HttpMethods.IsGet(method)) return HttpMethod.Get;
        if (HttpMethods.IsHead(method)) return HttpMethod.Head;
        if (HttpMethods.IsOptions(method)) return HttpMethod.Options;
        if (HttpMethods.IsPost(method)) return HttpMethod.Post;
        if (HttpMethods.IsPut(method)) return HttpMethod.Put;
        if (HttpMethods.IsTrace(method)) return HttpMethod.Trace;
        return new HttpMethod(method);
    }
}
```

Bonus : some other Rewriter

```
public class PrefixRewriter : IUrlRewriter
{
    private readonly PathString _prefix;
    private readonly string _newHost;

    public PrefixRewriter(PathString prefix, string newHost)
    {
        _prefix = prefix;
        _newHost = newHost;
    }

    public Task<Uri> RewriteUri(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_prefix))
        {
            var newUri = context.Request.Path.Value.Remove(0, _prefix.Value.Length) + context.Request.QueryString;
            var targetUri = new Uri(_newHost + newUri);
            return Task.FromResult(targetUri);
        }

        return Task.FromResult((Uri)null);
    }
}

public class MergeRewriter : IUrlRewriter
{
    private readonly List<IUrlRewriter> _rewriters = new List<IUrlRewriter>();
    public MergeRewriter()
    {
    }
    public MergeRewriter(IEnumerable<IUrlRewriter> rewriters)
    {
        if (rewriters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rewriters));

        _rewriters.AddRange(rewriters);
    }

    public MergeRewriter Add(IUrlRewriter rewriter)
    {
        if (rewriter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rewriter));

        _rewriters.Add(rewriter);

        return this;
    }

    public async Task<Uri> RewriteUri(HttpContext context)
    {
        foreach (var rewriter in _rewriters)
        {
            var targetUri = await rewriter.RewriteUri(context);
            if(targetUri != null)
            {
                return targetUri;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

// In Statup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IUrlRewriter>(new MergeRewriter()
        .Add(new PrefixRewriter("/POC/API", "http://localhost:1234"))
        .Add(new SingleRegexRewriter(@"^/POC/(.*)", "http://192.168.7.73:3001/$1")));
}
```

## Edit

I found a project to do same but with way more other feature https://github.com/damianh/ProxyKit as a nuget package

Comment: That is beautiful! Thank you! Works a treat!

Comment: You should add some logging statments and try catch.