# ASP.NET Core HttpClient accept all certificates for localhost only, otherwise behave normally

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to replicate the normal certificate validation for anything other than requests to localhost

```
    public static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        MaxConnectionsPerServer = int.MaxValue,
        UseCookies = false,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ValidateLocalhostCertificate
    });

    private static bool ValidateLocalhostCertificate(HttpRequestMessage arg1, X509Certificate2 arg2, X509Chain arg3, SslPolicyErrors arg4)
    {
        if (arg1.RequestUri.Host == "127.0.0.1")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // default validation
        }
    }
```

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core application using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414657/2220763) to reverse proxy requests made from specific subdomains to local services (e.g. `1.mywebsite.com` goes to `127.0.0.1:1001`, `2.mywebsite.com` goes to `127.0.0.1:1002`, etc.)

**PLEASE don't suggest IIS URL rewrites or any other method for doing this**

I'm assuming that client => mywebsite over 443 is secure, and the only 'unsecure' bit using the answer linked above would be happening locally on the server when it ignores invalid certificates to the local services (which all run strictly on https, something I can't change) - if this is untrue please correct me!

I've tried scouring the core source code but I'm struggling to find how HttpClient typically validates certificates

Comment: Or you can sign and install your own localhost cert and not mess with the code.

Comment: @Jasen I originally tried that and it didn't work. I'll give it another go on monday in case I had done something wrong

Comment: @Jasen yeah, no 

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: certificate is trusted root etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime checks certificate before a call to callback.

So certificate already checked and you can just check `arg4` for error.